# the list updated within a class

Tags: python, list, class

```
class A(object):
    aalist = []
    ai = 0
    def __init__(self):
    self.ablist = list()
    def add(self):
        self.aalist.append(["a","a"])
        self.ablist.append(["b","b"])
        self.ai = self.ai + 1
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.bblist = list()
    def badd(self):
        self.bblist.append(['c','c'])
for i in range(1,4):
    c = B()
    c.add()
    c.badd()
    print c.aalist,c.ablist,c.bblist,c.ai
```

run these codes , the result prompts:

```
[['a', 'a']] [['b', 'b']] [['c', 'c']] 1
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']] [['b', 'b']] [['c', 'c']] 1
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']] [['b', 'b']] [['c', 'c']] 1
```

I don't know why list get updated in the loop whereas the int seems to keeps static

Comment: You have an indentation error in the method `A.__init__`

Answer (score 2):

You're doing completely different operations with them.  Note that you *assign* a **new** integer to `self.ai` when you do `self.ai = self.ai + 1`.  When you work with the list, you work on it in place using `append`.  Also note that since you're working with an `int` (which is immutable), you *can't* change it's value in place.

There's also evidence that you're exploring class variables vs. instance variables here.  Note that in your example, `ablist` and `bblist` are instance variable whereas `aalist` is a class variable.  You can access them all the same way within a method (`self.XXlist`), but when you mutate `self.aalist`, you'll mutate the version *on the class*.  In other words, `self.aalist is A.aalist` will return `True`.  This allows all instances of your class to share the same list.  When one updates the list, all the other instances will know immediately (unless they bind an instance level attribute with the same name -- That variable will then take precedence in the attribute lookup).

Comment: To summary your question:  int is immutable and list is mutable, when i do self.ai = self.ai+1 and self.aalist.append['a','a'], they both call for A.ai/alist, but ai just reference to a new object and aalist refer just the same one because the mutable type.

Comment: @wllbll -- Well, even if `int` was mutable, you'd still see the same behavior because assignment creates a new reference.  So, if you change `ai` to `ai = []` and then you do `self.ai = self.ai + ['foo']`, you'll notice that `self.ai` is no longer the same thing as `A.ai` because you did an assignment.  This is one of the more tricky things to learn about python, but if you take your time and digest this one, then you're sure to have a much better understanding of the language.