# Python Global Variables in Class?

Tags: python, class, variables, global

I have a list of instances of my Business class. I'm used to defining the variables for a class at the top of the class. On of the variables in the Business class is a list of tags. When I loop through the list of businesses some have tags, some don't. Out of the 20 businesses the 4th element in the list has 4 tags. After these tags are added to this business all following instances of Business also share these tags. Here is my Business class-

```
from tag import *

class Business:
    name = ""
    website = ""
    phone = ""
    address = ""
    city = ""
    state = ""
    postalCode = ""
    tags = []
    data = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.setName(name)

    # Modifiers

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setWebsite(self, website):
        self.website = website

    def setPhone(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone

    def addTag(self, Tag):
        self.tags.append(Tag)

    def setAddress(self, address):
        self.address = address

    def setCity(self, city):
        self.city = city

    def setState(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def setPostalCode(self, postalCode):
        self.postalCode = postalCode

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def unset(self, key):
        del self.data[key]

    # Accessors

    def getWebsite(self):
        return self.website

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getPhone(self):
        return self.phone

    def getTags(self):
        return self.tags

    def getAddress(self):
        return self.address

    def getCity(self):
        return self.city

    def getState(self):
        return self.state

    def getPostalCode(self):
        return self.postalCode

    def get(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def getKeys(self):
        return self.data.keys()

    # Helpers
```

And a tag is added to a business like this-

```
if len(categories) > 1:
    for cat in categories:
        B.addTag(Tag(cat))
```

Are the variables defined at the top of my business class global to all instances of Business? How do I fix this problem?

Comment: This is a very common problem.  see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15489578/748858) for explanation.

Comment: Or, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13070948/748858) is another one.

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mutables assigned that way are "global" to the class.  To make them "local," define them as instance variables.  To do this for tags, for example, *remove* the global definition that you have and add instead a line to __init__ like:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.setName(name)
    self.tags = []
```

This assigns that value of tags to `self` rather than to the class generally.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it this way instead:

```
from tag import *

class Business:
    def __init__(self, name, website='', phone='', address='', city='', state='', postal_code='', tags=None, data=None):
        self.name        = name
        self.website     = website
        self.phone       = phone
        self.address     = address
        self.city        = city
        self.state       = state
        self.postal_code = postal_code

        self.tags        = []
        if tags is not None:
            for tag in tags:
                self.add_tag(tag)

        self.data        = {} if data is None else data

    def add_tag(self, tag):
        if not isinstance(tag, Tag):
            tag = Tag(tag)
        self.tags.append(tag)

    def add_data(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def remove_data(self, key):
        del self.data[key]

    def get_data(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def get_data_keys(self):
        return self.data.keys()
```

Python generally avoids getters and setters unless some extra processing or error-checking is required

Comment: Alright that works. But what not use getting and setter methods? Isn't it a good habit to add this layer of abstraction?